# How should I use VBA to scrape the drop-down menu (time to maturity) of APPL options on Yahoo Finance?

Tags: vba, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I want to use VBA to scrape the drop_down menu(time to maturity)of APPL options on Yahoo Finance.(https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/options?p=AAPL).I don't know how to write the codes

Comment: I am a beginner in VBA. Could anybody recommend an Excel VBA script?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub GET_DATE()
Dim ASHT As Worksheet, HttpUrl As String, ticker As String
Set ASHT = ActiveSheet
ticker = ASHT.Cells(8, "M")
If Len(ticker) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Ticker was empty! Please check"
        Exit Sub
End If
HttpUrl = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & ticker & "/options?p=" & ticker
'"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & ticker & "/options?date=" & dt2 & "&p=" & ticker
Debug.Print HttpUrl
ASHT.Range(ASHT.Cells(8, "P"), ASHT.Cells(ASHT.[P65535].End(3).Row + 1, "P")) = ""
Call GET_AND_PRINT_DATE(HttpUrl, ASHT)
MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Info"
End Sub
```